# Does Gmail disable ECMAScript completely?

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

Does Gmail filter `<script>` tags in e-mails?

I couldn't find examples nor the answer. This is for HTML formatted e-mails.

If yes, does it filter JavaScript in HTML elements like in `HREF="JavaScript:`?

Comment: Yes, it does. See e.g. [does Gmail or any other popular webmail service scrub javascript from html emails? if not, any reason why?](http://superuser.com/q/430562) More when Googling `gmail execute javascript`

Comment: @Pekka웃 : Ok, It seems Stack Exchange need to enhance it's search engine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail strips out any content between  tags before displaying the message. If an e-mail has script tags in it it doesn't mean google will automatically mark it as spam but it could be one of the things that increases the chance.

Comment: Is JavaScript allowed in some case (whether this just external script and the `<script  >` tag which are filtered)? Or are all ecmascript languages disabled completely?

Comment: there's no point in sending e-mails containing JavaScript (even if it does something useful) because it will almost certainly get blocked when the message is viewed and could contribute towards it getting marked as spam.

Comment: Actually, the problem is the Viewport (vw, vh, vmin, vmax) units are Supported in very few Software (considering Imap clients). So, I need to use Javascript...

Comment: It's not going to be possible. It would have catastrophic security implications.